# setImageResource in android

Tags: android, imageview

I am creating an app which dynamically load pictures from script and display them in grid view.

Here is code.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }


    private String[] mThumbIds = new String[]{
            "http://localhost/comic_app/index.php?id=1",
            "http://localhost/comic_app/index.php?id=67",
            "http://localhost/comic_app/index.php?id=4",
            "http://localhost/comic_app/index.php?id=89",
            "http://localhost/comic_app/index.php?id=98",
            "http://localhost/comic_app/index.php?id=23",
            "http://localhost/comic_app/index.php?id=45",
    };
}
```

I am getting compile time error on

> imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
>
> Error: cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

I know setImageResource wants to get int but how to do that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: convert response into bitmap and then setImageReource

Comment: in place of setImageReource()  use Picaso library to load image from url, other wise you well get outOfMemory exception. Check this:http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: you can't use local host url in app.

Comment: Try out `imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(mThumbIds[position]));`

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imageView.setImageResource()` expects an image from `Drawable`, and that is an int, e.g.: `R.drawable.sample`

You can load images from URL directly; you have to use an [image loading library](https://github.com/square/picasso) like `Picasso` for that.

Use

```
Picasso.with(context).load(mThumbIds[position]).into(imageView);
```

add this in your build.gradle file:

```
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: What changes should i need to made in my present code after adding that library.

Comment: see the library samples

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps:

1) Add dependencies to your Gradle.

```
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

2) Replace This line from your code

```
imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
```

with

```
Picasso.with(context).load(mThumbIds[position]).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```